# how to get turkish data from url and search in database in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a webservice for android app. Right now it has very simple task; get search name from app send it to `/test.php?pid=(searchname)`. It's working perfect when search has English characters. But when search has Turkish characters like

> ü,ş,ğ,ç,ö

it's not working. So i decided to try in web browser. i type `/test.php?pid=kırmızı` (`kırmızı`=red in English) and press enter, PHP gets 0 result. after that I press F5 and PHP gets 51 results that contain "kırmızı". I did not change `/test.php?pid=kırmızı`, just press F5. This is what my server logs looks like:

> GET /test.php pid=k%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1 HTTP/1.1 (type and enter = 0 result)
>
> GET /test.php pid=k%FDrm%FDz%FD HTTP/1.1 (press F5 = 51 results)

i tried `rawurldecode`, `urldecode` even functions that convert "k%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1". But it didn't work. This is my last code:

```
$pid =  urldecode($_GET['pid']);
$result= odbc_exec($cx, "SELECT * FROM yorumlanan WHERE ad LIKE '%$pid%'");
```

This code works perfect when search has only English letters. It even works with Turkish letters when refreshing page manually. But android app does not refresh page. So it sees 0 result.

Comment: try to use `urlencode` not `urldecode`.

Comment: @learner still 0 result when i use urlencode even F5 gets 0 result.

Comment: Can you print the SQL queries and try running it on the dabase using the native database client like mysql (if you are using mysql)